# Guidance with inheritance/overriding?

Tags: java, inheritance

The program is an 'appointments program', what the monthly class needs to do is In Monthly, if a query date is no earlier than the appointment date and matches the date in the month then the occursOn method should return true. For instance, suppose you have a monthly appointment, “go hiking”, set on 20 May 2003. For a query date, 20 May 2012, the method occursOn should return true.

I assume occursOn method needs to be overwritten but I want guidance here, as this is one of the few inheritance programs I have done.

I have 3 classes at the moment

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AppointmentDemo
{        
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {            
        Appointment[] appointments = new Appointment[2];
        appointments[0] = new Monthly(2003, 5, 20, "Go hiking.");
        appointments[1] = new Onetime(2012, 4, 2, "Dentist appointment.");        

        System.out.println("Enter a date (year month day) to list appointments: (e.g. 2000 8 13)");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int year = in.nextInt();
        int month = in.nextInt();
        int day = in.nextInt();
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++)
        {
            if (appointments[i].occursOn(year, month, day))
            {
                found = true;
                System.out.println(appointments[i]);
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            System.out.println("No appointment found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Which is the main class

the super class:

```
public class Appointment
{
    private String description;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    public Appointment(int year, int month, int day, String description)
    {
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getYear() { return year; }

    /**
     Returns the month of the appointment
     @return the month
     */
    public int getMonth() { return month; }

    /**
     Returns the day of the appointment
     @return the day
     */
    public int getDay() { return day; }

    public boolean occursOn(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        return (year == this.year) && (month == this.month) && (day == this.day);
    }

    /**
     Converts appointment to string description
     */
    public String toString() { return description; }
}
```

and a monthly class

```
public class Monthly extends Appointment {
    private int year;
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private String description;

    public Monthly(int year, int month, int day, String description) {
        super(year, month, day, description);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }           
}
```

Comment: What's the question??

Comment: @tnw the first sentence pretty much, where would be a good starting point to create this monthly class

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite `occursOn` in `Monthly` so that it doesn't check `year`.